# How to see Asan output after application finished

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, address-sanitizer

I have an application built with address sanitizer for macOS. When address sanitizer triggers, my application dies. How to watch what causing an error after application closed. The problem is that address sanitizer writes its output to stderr, and I didn't find a simple way to watch application's stderr. So what are the possibilities I have to watch asan output? Maybe I can somehow catch asan signal and log its output in code? Or maybe I can redirect asan output.

Comment: Can't you just run in a debugger? It'll break at the point asan fails

Comment: I do it for autotests, so I cannot run app from IDE or gdb. I need to run it as regular application.

Comment: Don't your tests just produce a pass or fail though then you can go and investigate the failures with gdb?